# Laravel migration - add new column to exists table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, migration

I have some  table and I want to add new column to this table. I want add string column with nullable default value.

I try add it like that

```
Schema::table('table', function (Blueprint $table) {

        $table->addColumn('string', 'label')->nullable()->change();
    });
```

or

```
Schema::table('table', function (Blueprint $table) {

        $table->addColumn('string', 'label')->nullable();
    });
```

but I have this error `here is no column with name 'label' on table.`

Answer (score 1):

Using the migration command you can add a new column to the existing table and the command is given below

Use command :

```
Php artisan make:migration add_column_name_table_name --table=table_name
```

After this command, one migration is created in “database/migrations”

```
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('custom_id')->after('id')->nullable();
  });
```

After that use another command

```
Php artisan migrate
```